# How to access/mount an unknown type of file?

Tags: files, mount, dd, loop-device

Back in 2012 I created a 7.5GB file named

`SD-card.2012.dd-bs1024-1.ec6a4994f4148912abb199505b98f01g`

My guess is that I ran `dd` on an 8GB SD card from one of my cameras.  Why? 
Can't remember.

I confirmed that `ec6a4994f4148912abb199505b98f01g` in its filename is its md5sum, so the file is intact relative to whenever I added its sum to its name.

`file` reports that is data.

`partx` reports 'failed to read partition table'. never used partx before.

`fdisk` reports 'doesn't contain a valid partition table'

`sudo losetup  -f <filename>` puts it at /dev/loop0 as reported by `losetup  -a`, but doesn't make any loop0pN, and my subsequent attempts at `mount -t <type> /dev/loop0 <mount-point>` fail as above.

`mount -o loop -t auto` fails, saying I need to specify the filesystem type.  It also fails if I specify vfat or ntfs.

Seeking advice on how to proceed.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device

Comment: `partx` and `fdisk` report no partition table

Comment: `photorec` the loop device? or `hexdump -C | less`, `binwalk`, ...

Comment: thanks for `hexdump -C`; I see a camera model (which is one of mine) and sensible dates and times. I don't have photorec in any repositories, but I'll look into that if it comes down to that.

Answer (score 2):

Make a loop device yourself and inspect what's in it from there. This can be accomplished with the following (with commands updated to reflect your environment, if these do not):

Find an unused loop device:

```
losetup -f
```

Create a loop device with that SD card file:

```
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/SD-card.2012.dd bs1024-1.ec6a4994f4148912abb199505b98f01g
```

Since it's an SD card, it probably doesn't *have* a partition table, and likely has just a filesystem sitting directly on it. You can now address `/dev/loop0` as a block special, and see about what kind of filesystem might be on it.

Display filesystems as scannable by your system:

```
blkid
```

When you know what the filesystem / partition structure is, try to mount it. YMMV, as you might have something odd on that SD card (such as LVM). But it's probably a filesystem directly on it:

```
mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/foo
```

Comment: after `losetup  -f <filename>` and `losetup -a`; `blkid -p /dev/loop0` does not report anything at all.  I'm not sure what you mean by *can now address /dev/loop0 as a block special*

Comment: I mean that you can access your file as a block device directly now that it's being addressed by loop0. If blkid doesn't spit out something immediately, you;re going to have to probe around it a bit. fdisk or parted could be useful in this case, at least to see if there is a partition structure on it. You could also try mounting it to see if we can automatically determine the contents of /dev/loop0. Finally, the file command can be very useful here, with the -s switch to read special devices. Such as: `file -sL /dev/loop0`

Comment: `fdisk /dev/loop0` reports 'Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor ...'

Comment: `file -sL /dev/loop0` reports it to be 'sticky data'. Time for me to find out what that means

Comment: I'm interested to know what that means, too. I don't see much on it aside from bewildered people with inaccessible disks that are using file to determine their contents before mounting. Are you sure this has valid data, or do you have any idea what it might have on it? Or do you know what filesystem it could have? I'd guess FAT, if it came from a camera. Some details like that would help at this point, as we could use something like `testdisk` to scan the thing for lost or damaged partition tables and / or filesystems.